# Why some fields are public and some have properties?

Tags: .net, properties, standards

Just saw few tutorials and was quite confused that authors sometimes uses both properties with no restrictions and public fields. I cannot see any reason for doing that. Should not I use it just everytime just to be consistent with "standard"?

```
class A
{
  public bool B;

  private bool c
  public bool C
  {
    get
    {
      return c 
     }
    set
    {
      c=value;
     }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using public fields is almost *always* a bad idea. [Just use properties](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx).

You should also be aware of *automatically implemented properties* (introduced in C# 3), which allow your `C` property to be written as:

```
public bool C { get; set; }
```

Comment: Automatic properties were introduced in C# 3.0.

Comment: Automatically implemented? What does it mean, the Visual Studio will generate this code for me?

Comment: @Cocodrilo: It means you put that source code in your C# code, and the compiler generates a property which is backed by a private field. See the C# spec for details.

Comment: @Oded: Thanks - I'm hoping that relatively few people are using C# 2 or 1 now, even if they still have to target .NET 2...

Comment: @JonSkeet - Do you still see it as problematic to use public fields on a DTO (an object that does not have any behavior and only stores data)?

Comment: @smartcaveman: I would still prefer to use properties - especially as they're so easy to write with automatically implemented properties. There are benefits in terms of binding, breakpoints - and the ability for the type to evolve over time and gain behaviour if necessary.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I read your article and I understand the benefits of using properties over fields.  I'm still not convinced that using a property on a pure data object is a better design choice.  My thought is that a public field on a DTO makes the behavior of setting a value more clear to the consumer.   With a public property, the caller doesn't know if there is any validation or implicit value-changed notifications.  Also, the ability to use methods with `ref` and `out` parameters can lead to writing less code when populating a DTO's values (e.g. `int.TryParse()`.

Comment: Also, regarding the Type evolving over time - I don't see how this could be problematic with a DTO.  It seems like making the Type unsuitable for a non-DTO context would actually enforce correct usage of the Type as a DTO.  I understand the limitations that come with making a field public, but if this limitation is intentional, is it still problematic?  What am I missing?

Comment: @smartcaveman: Just a matter of taste, really. If you want to do so, go ahead - just don't say I didn't warn you when you want to put in some validation, or even just logging, and you lose compatibility :)

Answer (score 0):

It is always a better practice to have private fields. You should use standard coding guidelines which makes the code consistent.

You can totally eliminate the use of private fields by using the automatic implemented properties.

```
Public int MyProperty {get; set;}
```

You can also have private set for the properties so that they can not be set outside the scope of the class, which is like making a read only property

```
Public int MyProperty {get; private set;}
```